# how to put recyclerview on bottom of spinner

Tags: android, xml, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I was using Constraint layout in a fragment. I had set TopToBottomOf although it wasn't reaching to bottom.

```xml
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCallLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterSpinner" />
```

[image]

I had set it `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterSpinner"`. I want to put recyclerView on bottom of Spinner. I want to achieve it without margin.

Seems like constraint layout isn't working in the page. Hence I am showing the whole xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.DialerFragment">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCallLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterSpinner" />

    <com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller
        android:id="@+id/fastscroll_dialer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:fastscroll__bubbleColor="#5e64ce"
        app:fastscroll__handleColor="#8f93d1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/recyclerViewCallLog"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerViewCallLog" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do `0dp` height for `RecyclerView`. like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/filterSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCallLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterSpinner" />

    <com.futuremind.recyclerviewfastscroll.FastScroller
        android:id="@+id/fastscroll_dialer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:fastscroll__bubbleColor="#5e64ce"
        app:fastscroll__handleColor="#8f93d1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/recyclerViewCallLog"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerViewCallLog" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```